# When posting to an ApiController the 2nd parameter is null

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, asp.net-apicontroller

I am writing an API which will receive via post a UTF-16 encoded string of data which is in reality XML. The problem I am running into is the data parameter in the controller method signature is null. The first paramater, which is the API key is just fine. I have read every question/answer on Stack Overflow I can find, plus several other sources, to no avail.

Here is my controller method :

```
[HttpPost]
public string PostEmployeeData(string key, [FromBody]string data)
{            
    return "Emp data posted";
}
```

Here's a screenshot of my Postman chrome plug-in settings:
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you make this request? What does that code look like?

Comment: I'm using the Postman Chrome plug-in for testing. Ultimately, I don't have control over the app that will be calling my API. I attached a screen shot of my Postman settings to the original post.

Comment: The body needs a parameter named `data`. And check the `Content-Type` request header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue like this:

```
var bodyStream = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream);
bodyStream.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
var bodyText = bodyStream.ReadToEnd();
```

Thanks to joshhendo for giving me the info I needed to head in this direction.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to get the raw contents of the body, you could do:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string PostEmployeeData(string key)
    {
        var data = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        return "Emp data posted";
    }
```

To have it as an input parameter, the data needs to be of a valid format with the appropriate `Content-Type` set. See [this post](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Dec/13/Accepting-Raw-Request-Body-Content-with-ASPNET-Web-API) for more information.

It would be possible to further improve this by properly implementing `async` and `await`, however that isn't essential.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar. I posted my solution. Marking as the answer because this set me down the road I eventually took.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in Postman you need to set on *Headers* tab:

**Content-Type** = *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*

And on *Body* tab select *Raw* option and write your value starting the **=** sign, for example:

```
=mydata
```

this variable will be the *data* variable in your action definition.